# bash dialog prevent exit

Tags: bash, dialog

I have a bash script with dialog `--checklist`

This comes with an `OK` and `cancel` button.

When I press `cancel`, the script exits and returns to shell.

How do I remove the `cancel` button or prevent the user to enter shell?

```
    #!/bin/bash
set -e
rm -f /tmp/output
rm -f /oke/harddisk
rm -f /tmp/hdbron1
rm -f /tmp/hdbron2
output=`echo /tmp/output`
hd1=/tmp/hdbron1
hd2=/tmp/hdbron2
hd3=/tmp/output

#lsblk -d -e 11,7 -dio size,model | sed 1d | awk '$1=$1' | tr " " "_" | sed -e "s/$/ \/\  /"> /tmp/hdbron2
lsblk -d -e 11,7 -dio size,model | awk '!($1 ~ "M")'| sed 1d | awk '$1=$1' | tr " " "_" | sed -e "s/$/ \/\  /"> /tmp/hdbron2
lsblk -d -e 11,7 | grep "disk" | awk '!($4 ~ "M")'| awk '{print $1}' > /tmp/hdbron1
paste $hd1 $hd2 | paste > /tmp/output

dialog --checklist "Selecteer doel schijf:" 60 90 60 \
$(cat /tmp/output) 2>/oke/harddisk
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to read [the documentation of dialog](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) ?

There's a `--nocancel`  that seems to do the job:

```
--nocancel
    Suppress the "Cancel" button in checklist, inputbox and menu box modes. A script can still test if the user pressed the ESC key to cancel to quit.
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But the cancel button is still there. With the --nocancel button my script doesnt work anymore.

Comment: The same doc mentions "--no-cancel" as well. Maybe this is the option you need to test ?

Comment: That worked.. But putting it before --checklist helps too... ;-) Thank you